# Detect svg element outside browser window

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm writing a mind map using d3.js. When a node contains a lot of children some of them are not visible on the browser window. I support navigation through nodes using up/down/left/right keys.

The problem is: when I navigate to nodes which aren't visible (outside of browser window) the browser doesn't automatically scroll to show this node. How can I scroll the window to show appropriate node? I'm looking for browser independent method

Comment: What code are you currently using to scroll to the elements? [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: None. I read about some solutions but they all noticed they aren't browser independent

Comment: Research the `viewBox` attribute. It tells the browser which part of the SVG to display in the SVG view port.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for long time without response. I ended up using getBoundingClientRect(). For each node I call this function and if:

1. top < 0 or
2. left < 0 or
3. bottom > window.innerHeight
4. right > window.innerWidth

I call translate on my root node which moves tree.